# Black lines on the sides of mp4 video - iPhone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, html5-video

I am building a website and have added an mp4 video using html5 video tag.
**The problem is that when I open the website on my iPhone (any browser - Chrome, Firefox, Safari), I see black lines on the side of the video frame** (as described in the picture below).

This is how I am adding the video:

```
<div id="landing_page_video" class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-7">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">          
    <video preload="auto" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
       <source src="img/landing_page_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

[confidential video content chalked out]

[image: Landing Page Video]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CSS as well? couldn't you do:

```
#landing_page_video{
border: 0 none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```